# Clinical Papers Proving Benefits of Oil Pulling

Tags: dentistry, ancient-medicine

I am researching oil pulling, i.e. practice of swishing oil in mouth for several minutes to remove dental bacteria.

Ancient medicine says it reduces tooth sensitivity, pain, prevents gingivitis.

Where can I find actual clinical studies touting the benefits.

Here is what I find so far .... any guidance will be most helpful

https://www.webmd.com/oral-health/features/oil-pulling

https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/oil-pulling-coconut-oil

Comment: Did you notice the "Sources" link at the bottom of the WebMD article? You might want to start there.

Comment: Related - https://health.stackexchange.com/q/10765